# javascript addEventListener in for loops uses last variable for event

Tags: javascript, html

here's my code

```
    <body>
        <div id = "elementbox">
        </div>
<script>
var container = document.getElementById("elementbox");
function item_select() {
alert("e");
var selected_element = document.getElementsByClassName("on");
selected_element.className = "off";
alert(selected_element);
}
for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    dive = document.createElement("div");
    dive.id = i+1;
    dive.className = "off";
    if (dive.id === 8) { dive.className = "on"}
    dive.innerHTML = "<p>E</p>;
    (function(i) {
        dive.addEventListener("click", function(i) {
        document.getElementById(i).className = "on";
        item_select();
        }, true)
    })(i);
container.appendChild(dive);
```

}

```
</script>

    </body>
</html>
```

As you can see my addEventListener uses the incremented variable (i) to change the className of a specific div, so when the event is called i is equal to 20.
how can I avoid this ?

Comment: Is this the exact code you're using? Does your JS console complain about the missing `"` in `dive.innerHTML = "<p>E</p>;`?

Comment: What about putting the handler on the container instead so you don't have to deal with this problem? You can get anything you want from the clicked element by using event.target in your handler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, I don't believe that is what is going on. You already have immediate-invocation to close the value of `i`.

I think the problem is that `i` is the `event` object:

```
(function(i) {
    dive.addEventListener("click", function(i) {
                                            ^-- i should not be here
        document.getElementById(i).className = "on";
        item_select();
    }, true)
})(i);
```

---

It seems your click handler sets the class `on` to the *next* `<div>`. Consider using `dive.nextSibling`. This avoids the need to use `id` and `i`. It's possible that more complex behaviour is required so maybe having the `id` is useful.

Comment: I need the id but besides the fact that I put the i, how can i avoid that the last i is taken (maybe make some sort of copy) ?. Or how can I know the id of the element clicked ?

Comment: The immediate-invocation (`(function (i) {}(i))`) already 'copies' the value of `i`. To know the `id` of an element in the onclick handler you can do `this.id` as `this` points to the DOMElement.